# HTML Code doesn't contain the string I want

Tags: android, html, kotlin

I recently asked a question on how to get the HTML code from a Google API Script that fed me an IP Address, and received an answer that told me to use this Utility Class. (I am coding this in Kotlin)

```
package com.example.myapplication

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import java.io.BufferedReader
import java.io.InputStreamReader
import java.net.MalformedURLException
import java.net.URL

object ContentScrapper {


    fun getHTMLData(activity: AppCompatActivity,url: String, scrapListener: ScrapListener) {
        Thread(Runnable {

            val google: URL?
            val `in`: BufferedReader?
            var input: String?
            val stringBuffer = StringBuffer()

            try {
                google = URL(url)
                `in` = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(google.openStream()))
                while (true) {
                    if (`in`.readLine().also { input = it } == null)
                        break
                    stringBuffer.append(input)
                }
                `in`.close()

                activity.runOnUiThread {
                    scrapListener.onResponse(stringBuffer.toString())
                }
            } catch (e: MalformedURLException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
                activity.runOnUiThread {
                    scrapListener.onResponse(null)
                }
            }
        }).start()

    }


    interface ScrapListener {
        fun onResponse(html: String?)
    }
}
```

And called it using this

```
ContentScrapper.getHTMLData(this, url, object : ContentScrapper.ScrapListener{
            override fun onResponse(html: String?) {
                if(html != null) {
                    editTexttest.setText(html)
                } else {
                    editTexttest.setText("Not Found")
                }
            }
        })
```

However, I was unable to find the string that was displayed on my screen. Below is the link that I am currently using to get the string. The HTML code that is returned to me doesn't seem to contain the string that the url below provides. Is there anything wrong with how I called it? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyjRIRl2ca_pnfz8XgccjDlaRPUNz6KY_WcyPZAROsy9EZkD35F/exec?command=GetLock1IPAddress

Comment: why don't you use jsoup library ?

Comment: I have heard of jsoup library, and I am currently trying to learn how to use it. Thanks

Comment: This is the cause of the problem. You must be signed in to the Google service.You are asked to login to send a request to the relevant url and get its content. For this reason it does not work.